# Android - How to detect if alarm has been set (alarmmanager)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I've got a 'welcome' screen which downloads the times that the alarms should go off, however each time the user lands on the screen a new alarm is set

this of course causes multiple alarms

is there any way you can detect if one has been set for today?

thanks for your help in advance

Andy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set alarm with same pending intent then previous alarm will be cancelled and reset again.if you want to cancel any alarm then you can cancel that alarm by  alarmManager.cancel(operation).
If you set an alarm like this.

```
  PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyAlarm.this,0,intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), sender);
```

Then you cancel that alarm by the following way.

```
 alarmManager.cancel(sender);
```

Comment: Ah ok, so if i use the same code that contains the intent which sets the alarm then the previous intent will be updated with the new time?

Comment: yes.Please see the documentation.  public void set (int type, long triggerAtTime, PendingIntent operation)

Since: API Level 1
Schedule an alarm. Note: for timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler. If there is already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, it will first be canceled.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: I've used a handler for some other tasks, are you saying for alarms I should just use handlers as well?
Thanks for this help jainal

Answer (score 2):

Not via the Android API. You have to save the times yourself to SharedPreferences or some file if you want to look them up later.